# Looping and iterating within a nested list data

Tags: python, database, list, api, nested

```
id_ucprice = [[47348, 22900], [48340, 14700], [4834934, 14700], [348348, 15300]]

for ids in id_ucprice:
    for x in range(ids[1]):
        post_data = {
            'price': ids[1],
            'overpriced_email_price_change': False,
            'apply_to_all': False,
            }
        for y in range(ids[0]):
            response = requests.post(f'apiurl/{ids[0]}/pricing', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=post_data)
            update_data = json.loads(response.text)
            response_price = update_data['priceCents']
            r_item = update_data['name']
            r_id = update_data['id']
            if response_price == ids[1]:
                print(style.MAGENTA + f'[{datetime.now()}] => Updated Price: {response_price/100:.2f} | ID = > {r_id} | Item => {r_item}')
```

I want each `[0]` and `[1]` to be used within their respective Request URL and jsondata but I am having trouble looping through each list. When I run it only uses the first one, `[47348, 22900]` and keeps using it without going throught the rest of the list

Comment: have you tried using a loop like this?  for x in range(id_ucprice.len-1)

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need a nested for loop. Otherwise in your current code, it will call `requests.post(f'apiurl/47348/pricing', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=post_data)` for 47348 times.

In the outer for loop `for ids in id_ucprice:`, we get `ids` like `[47348, 22900]`, etc. We can directly use `ids[0]` and `ids[1]` to generate the URL and call the API.

```py
id_ucprice = [[47348, 22900], [48340, 14700], [4834934, 14700], [348348, 15300]]

for ids in id_ucprice:
    post_data = {
        'price': ids[1],
        'overpriced_email_price_change': False,
        'apply_to_all': False,
    }

    response = requests.post(f'apiurl/{ids[0]}/pricing', cookies=cookies, headers=headers, json=post_data)
    update_data = json.loads(response.text)
    response_price = update_data['priceCents']
    r_item = update_data['name']
    r_id = update_data['id']
    if response_price == ids[1]:
        print(style.MAGENTA + f'[{datetime.now()}] => Updated Price: {response_price/100:.2f} | ID = > {r_id} | Item => {r_item}')
```

Comment: Yep I realized this and fixed my code. Thanks!